# My web page is reloading on pressing of a button? I have tried things like returning false from the js but still no solution?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Below is my html and java script code which displays google map and on clicking of a button displays the map's center coordinates. I have added "return false;" and "e.preventDefault();" statements later on to make the code work. But still on pressing the button, the page is reloading itself.

While i just want to extract the map's center and display results from DB on the same page without refreshing the map.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>The Test</title>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.key={my key}&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map 
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', updateMap);
        function updateMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
                                    {
                                        zoom: 5,
                                        center: {lat: centerLat, lng: centerLng},
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.NORMAL
                                    }
                );
        }
        var centerLat = 29; 
        var centerLng = 79;
        function getCenter(e){  
            value = map.getCenter();
            alert("get the centre");
            map.setZoom(8);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <div id="map" style="width:80%;height:400px;"></div>
        <button type="button" onClick="return getCenter()" style="width:10%">Get Center</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place the `button` outside the `form` tag?

Comment: Why is the button inside a form? It seems you're not posting anything...

Comment: The onsubmit and the type=button should stop any submission unless some error. Please look in the console

Comment: i have written form tag later on to try for solution. even placing button anywhere else or removing form tag doesn't solves problem

Comment: i can not reproduce the error, it will just work properly without reloading, please give us a not working fiddle. Also var map. Add a ; here

Comment: [The posted code works for me as well](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g1Lcc80m/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you mean something along these lines?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>The Test</title>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.key={my key}&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map ;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', updateMap);
        function updateMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
                                    {
                                        zoom: 5,
                                        center: {lat: centerLat, lng: centerLng},
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.NORMAL
                                    }
                );
        }
        var centerLat = 29; 
        var centerLng = 79;
        function getCenter(e){  
            value = map.getCenter();
            alert(value);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:80%;height:400px;"></div>
        <button onClick="getCenter()" style="width:10%">Get Center</button>
    </body>
</html>
```